# Java virtual Machine implementation iadd microcommand improvization

Tags: java, vm-implementation

Wanna ask some question of our computer structure exam here to be sure. Below is add command of Mic-1 IJVM. We were asked to write new `iaddtriple` command which will add three top words of stack and store it on the stack again.

```
iadd1 MAR = SP = SP − 1; rd Read in next-to-top word on stack
iadd2 H = TOS H = top of stack
iadd3 MDR = TOS = MDR + H;wr;go to Main1 Add two top words, write to top of stack
```

My answer was ;

```
iaddtriple1 MAR = SP = SP − 1; rd 
iaddtriple2 H = TOS H = 
iaddtriple3 H = MDR = TOS = MDR + H 
iaddtriple4 MAR = SP = SP − 1;
iaddtriple5 MDR = TOS = MDR + H ; wr;go to Main1
```

I want to ask if my `iaddtriple3` step is legal. One of my friends told me that `H=blabla +H` assignment should be illegal thus shouldn't be used. But time diagram of a data path cycle proves me right. Thanks in advance.

```
iaddtriple3  H = MDR = TOS = MDR + H
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to perform

```
H = H + MDR
```

since H can be specified in the C-bus bits, the ALU operation is A + B, the B register is MDR. The actual microinstruction would be

```
0003C8000
```

The first two hex digits could be any numbers, the third hex digit is 0 or 8.